# Apache Upgrade to 2.4.58 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to upgrade apache from 2.4.52 to 2.4.58 on a droplet with Digital Ocean running Ubuntu 22.04. My upgrade path is:

`sudo apt update`

And then:

`sudo apt install apache`

But I get a message thats says

`apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.52-lubuntu4.7)`

Comment: Why do you ned 2.4.58?

Comment: If you really need the newest version of Apache's HTTP server, you can download it [here](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi). But make sure to first uninstall Apache HTTP server using `apt remove apache`. PS I don't recommend doing so

Comment: Client has had an audit of the website done and its flagged up its running on apache 2.4.52 which was released on the 20 Dec 2021. [https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html](https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your audit is flawed. It is not enough to only check for version numbers. Package maintainers of large distributions backport all security fixes to the versions that are actively maintained.

You can see the fixes that have been applied in the [changelog of the package](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7/changelog). As long you install security updates you will also receive security fixes, even when the original software has them fixed in a newer version.

Currently the latest version of the Ubuntu 22.04 Apache package is 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7. Since you are already on that version, all known security issues are fixed. The most relevant version number in here is the last part, `ubuntu4.7`.

If you want to know if a security issue exists, get the CVE number of the issue and check it agains the changelog. They are usually fixed and provided as an updated package very fast.

Comment: Thanks, all makes sense. At least I can go back to them with an informative answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that version available in the version history of the official Ubuntu package.
https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7/changelog

The highest version is 2.4.52

Comment: Thanks, very useful; especially seeing update dates. As I think the client was worried its an outdated version from 2021 which is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you need to add apache repository by geven command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade apache2
```

Comment: This is a custom repo so that could make it unsupported

Comment: solution that I have read several times on various websites but not on any official site. We don't know if we can trust ondrej/ppa for use in a production environment.